# How to generate a try catch code block automatic in Android Studio by shortcut?

Tags: android-studio

In Eclipse, when I enter code `Thread.sleep(100)`, the code will be wrappered by try catch after entering keys: <kbd>ctrl+1</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>. In Android studio what can I do for wrapper it by try catch easily? Is there a shortcut?

Comment: I just find it in Android Studio's feature  'Tip of the Day',the shortcut is "Ctrl+Alt+T"

Comment: the property in keymap is Surround with

Comment: On the mac to seems to be COMMAND+OPTION+t

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Highlight the code you want to surround with try/catch

For **Windows** it is:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

For **Mac** it is:

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

Select the item you want (**#7** for try / catch)

There is no need to "*type*" try first however, highlighting your code works better.

Comment: for ubuntu better use keymap.  Ctrl + Alt + t is for terminal

Comment: In version 2019-03 on windows this launches then terminal.

Answer (score 14):

Highlight the necessary code you need to surround with, and press one of the key combinations depending upon your Operating System.

**Windows:** 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

**Linux(Ubuntu):**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

**Mac:**
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

A list of `Surround With` options would pop (like in the below image). You can select the appropriate item of your choice either by pressing the respective number of the item on keyboard or manually via mouse click.

[image: Surround With]

Comment: ubuntu works with `windows` key combination. thanks

Answer (score 8):

Type "try",
then press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>,
then select "try / catch".

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu Gnome, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> has been taken already by "Launch terminal", run command `gnome-control-center keyboard` to check:

[image]

Either you disable it by press `Back Space` OR use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> as alternative.

Keep in mind that if "try / catch" option doesn't shows up, it might caused by warning such as "unexpected token" in your code. You need to fix it first.

Answer (score 7):

**Try this**

1. Write 'try'
2. select this word(try)
3. press Ctrl-Alt-T
4. Select appropriate one

Answer (score 3):

On Mac it's: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Also for most used shortcuts in Android Studio I'd recommend this link http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-of-the-day-roundup-2/

Answer (score 1):

**Select the code** you want to surround with try/catch and **press Alt + Shift + Z**, this will bring up try/catch along with any other applicable templates like this:

[image: Try/Catch option in the resulting menu]

To generate a try/catch block **type 'try' and press ctrl + space**.

The Ctrl + Shift + T shortcut launches the terminal in the eclipse version I am using - 2019-03.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Cut of Generating predefined/custom templates**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Short Cut of Generating predefined/custom templates

Press Ctrl + Alt + T

Surround with many blocks like

- try/catch
- try/catch/finally
- if
- if/else
- {}
- < Edit fold > Commits

Answer (score 0):

type try and press tab button, it will create try/catch template easily

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).